# Find strings inside array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, implode

I have 2 arrays and am looking to find a value inside 1 of the arrays using PHP.

I realise I'd have to use the PHP `explode` function but I'm afraid that's where my skills end.

My function would compare the values of both arrays and if it finds any `$needle` values inside `$haystack`, it would return them inside `$found`. It could potentially find more than one, so perhaps `$found` should be an array too?

```
$needle = "Swimming,Landscaping,Gardening,Bricklaying,3D Modelling";
$haystack = "Football,Rugby,Landscaping,3D Modelling";
$found = magicFunction($needle,$haystick); 
// $found['0'] = "Landscaping";
// $found['1'] = "3D Modelling";
```

Does this make sense?

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$found = Array ();
$needle = "Swimming,Landscaping,Gardening,Bricklaying,3D Modelling";
$haystack = "Football,Rugby,Landscaping,3D Modelling";
$search = explode(',',$haystack);
foreach ( explode(',',$needle as $k => $v )
{
  if ( in_array ( $v, $search ) )
    $found[] = $v;
}
```

Or as David has said, you could use `array_intersect`:

```
$found = array_intersect ( explode( ',', $haystack ), explode( ',', $needle ) );
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP provides the handy function [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to do that.

```
$needle = "Swimming,Landscaping,Gardening,Bricklaying,3D Modelling";
$haystack = "Football,Rugby,Landscaping,3D Modelling";

$needle = explode(",", $needle);
$haystack = explode(",", $haystack);

$intersection = array_intersect($haystack, $needle);
print_r($intersection);
//Array ( [2] => Landscaping [3] => 3D Modelling )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can produce arrays from the needle and the haystack, then find intersect of the two arrays:

```
<?php

$needle = "Swimming,Landscaping,Gardening,Bricklaying,3D Modelling";
$haystack = "Football,Rugby,Landscaping,3D Modelling";

$needle = explode(',', $needle);
$haystack = explode(',', $haystack);


$found = array_intersect($needle, $haystack);

print_r($found);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/array_intersect

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is built in to PHP: `array_intersect`.

```
$a = explode(',', "Swimming,Landscaping,Gardening,Bricklaying,3D Modelling");
$b = explode(',', "Football,Rugby,Landscaping,3D Modelling");
$found = array_intersect($a, $b); 
print_r($found);
```

Output:
`Array
(
    [1] => Landscaping
    [4] => 3D Modelling
)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to explode the needles and look for occurrences using `strpos`.

```
$needles = explode(',', $needle);
foreach ($needles as $n)
{
      if (strpos($n, $haystack)) {  }
}
```

[Jan Hančič](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948650/559157) solution may be more appropriate and faster if you do not need the position of the string.